# Hiding rows with duplicate values based on one column

Tags: sql, database, filter

[image: Table Image]

I need to hide rows with duplicate values in a column labeled PartNumber. I do not care which line is shown, but I need all of the other columns still populated. Other columns have unique information so I cannot use distinct. I also do not need a highest value or latest, so no other post has what I need.

Comment: Would grouping by that column work?

Comment: Although possible in SQL, this type of data manipulation is more appropriately done at the application level.

Comment: what would I need to add to the code to alter this?

Comment: Look at olap functions if you using SQL Server.  Could use row_number() and partition by PartNumber returning only the first occurrence.

Comment: "what would I need to add to the code" -> To *what* code?